# macro to capture selected range and populate a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve the following using a macro. When I select a few cells in a range and then I click on a button, the selected cells should populate some value as "Y" as shown below.

[image: Request for your guidance]

```
Sub SELECTCELL()
mystring = Selection.Address(Row, Column)
```

I found this code, but don't know how to use this

```
    MsgBox mystring
    firstcell = Left(mystring, 2)
    MsgBox firstcell
    lastcell = Right(mystring, 2)
    MsgBox lastcell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you provided I would do something like this:

```
For Each Cell In Application.Selection
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column + 6).Value = "Y"
Next
```

Change the number 6 to be whatever offset you need.